# Bulk migrate documents from legacy to Salesforce

Tags: attachment, bulk-api, data-migration

I'm working in a data migration project and along with other data, I need to bulk migrate attachments from legacy platform to Salesforce. Is there an automated way to migrate the attachment data which is stored as a blob in legacy to Salesforce ?

I have reviewed https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/binary_intro.htm but the issue with this is that I need to have salesforce ParentIds for uploading attachment and I'll not be having it when migrating data from legacy.

Any pointers ?

Regards,
Avinash

Comment: so, the source documents are in some non-SFDC system?  You'll want to migrate to SFDC Files, not Attachments. Files are ContentVersion objects and you can create them in various ways, e.g. [Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.loader_content.htm&type=5); Later, you can write a script to associate the Files to other objects using ContentDocumentLink (a junction record)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is a bit trickier than it looks. And if you are using Communities (ADA Digital Experiences) then the `NetworkId` also needs to be set.

Two existing solutions; I've tried neither:

- [Magic Mover for Notes And Attachments to Lightning Experience](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EHAmyUAH) app from Salesforce Labs
- [Convert Attachments to Salesforce Files](https://github.com/sfdcaquibjaved/convert-attachment-to-files) GitHub project

and further Googling may reveal more options.